# Android - only the last item shows in layer-list

Tags: android, android-listview, shapes, divider

I'm trying to style the `divider` for `ListView`. What I want is just 2 simple horizontal lines.

**list.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ListView" >
</ListView>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ListView" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>

    <!-- 5dp: just to make sure there's enough space -->
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

**divider.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ffff" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The result is a horizontal line with `height of 5dp`(should be 2, isn't it?) and `color of red`(color of second item). The first item with color `#00ffff` does not show up at all.

Can someone please suggest the  code for **2 simple horizontal lines?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd better answer my own question...

It seems `styles.xml - style - item` takes the color of the `last item` in `layer-list` as background for the entire divider. This `last item` is on **top of other layers**, and that is why other items in the layer-list don't show up.

The key is **`padding`**.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ListView" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

**divider.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
            <padding android:top="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: divider]

So in my case I just need to change 10dp/5dp to 2dp/1dp to get 2 thin horizontal lines.

Comment: That's a good answer ! Only the last item background is used. In my case I had the last layer-list item to be just a stroke, so no shape and no color, that resulted in having a all black background ! (In android 4.4 it was working, but not in 2.2, not tested other APIs).